# Тот еще фрукт

Tags: фразеология

Когда о человеке хотят сказать, что он... ну, скажем так, не слишком хороший, о нем говорят: "Тот еще фрукт". Интересно, а почему именно фрукт, а не овощ или, например, ягода?))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Слово появилось у нас во времена Петра Первого (лат. fructus, от frui - употреблять что-либо для своего удовольствия, наслаждаться). Древесный плод, потребляемый, как лакомство.
(Источник: «Словарь иностранных слов, вошедших в состав русского языка». Чудинов А.Н., 1910)http://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-foreign2-term-39277.htm

Как и ко всем новшествам Петра, к заморским фруктам относились подозрительно, отсюда и о подозрительном человеке говорили "фрукт": Ну и фрукт этот... Это просторечно-презрительное значение усилилось  в выражении местоимением с частицей ТОТ ЕЩЁ (тот ещё пройдоха, тот ещё ворюга), в резуьтате такое экспрессивное выражение и получилось.